# How to generate huge report with images using SwapFileVirtualization

Tags: jasperserver

Trying to generate huge report designed in iReport 4.7.1, which include images in table first column , using SOAP to communicate to TIBCO jasperserver.

Not able to implement Virtualization(swapFileVirtualization), any help would be appreciable.

Comment: I am able to generate with image report for upto 1000 records but by using  ini_set('memory_limit', '-1') and  ini_set("default_socket_timeout", 6000) in my code.

Comment: I am able to generate with image report for upto 1000 records but by using  ini_set('memory_limit', '-1') and  ini_set("default_socket_timeout", 6000) in my code.Basically i am looking for solution based on Virtualization ....don't know how to implement built in REPORT_VIRTUALIZER in iReport.I am using php bit of my code like as follows :$report_unit = "/reports/folder/report_name";  
$report_format = "PDF";
$report_params = "";
$result = $client->requestReport($report_unit, $report_format,$report_params); Can i pass virtualization parameter from my code if so then how? Please help.Thanks